# Sketch Questions regarding symbols

Tags: sketch-app, symbols, generate-image-assets

**I've a few questions regarding Sketch -**

- Sketch keeps expanding my symbol folders, it seems random and makes it more challenging to find what I want.
- Is there an option for how Sketch organizes symbols? Currently they are laid out horizontally in one row and I have to manually lay them out differently.
- Some of my artboard are showing assets as "not symbols" when I had previously set them as symbols.
- When setting assets as exportable, do I need to set all of my assets as exportable? That is on all my artboard and on the symbols page.
- If I have repeated symbols, say a trash can in many locations? Should they all be set as exportable or just one? If they all are will it cause confusion with Zeplin?

I know these sound like newbie questions but my experience with Sketch has been fairly narrow and I just want to get my head around some best practices.

- Frank

Comment: For #1 I realized that when you select a symbol on it's artboard the rollout will expand. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I often faced a same issues with you, however, you may find these ideas work.

- Create a Sketch library file, and try to put symbols as much as you can.
- Make sure you manage important symbols on the library file.
- I recommend you not to manage symbols level-deeper. more than 4. When you try to manage level-deeper symbols, it often makes Sketch having problems whether the version is newer or not.